# Making a data set out of Json Data in Python

Tags: python, json, combobox

I have a ttk ComboBox in my project like so:

```
var = tkinter.StringVar()
var.set('Actually Additions Atomic Reconstructor')
p = ttk.Combobox(window, textvariable = var, values = data, justify='center')
p.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', box_text)
p.config(font='Helvetica 12 bold', width="30")
p.pack(side=TOP)
```

And then a data set with a string of items like this:

```
data={
'Advanced Mortars',
'Artisan Worktables',
'Initial Inventory',
'JEI Hide'
}
```

etc..

However I'm now wondering how I can take something like a json file I made, like this:

```
[{
"title": "Advanced Mortars",
"import": "import mods.advancedmortars.Mortar;"
}, {
"title": "Initial Inventory",
"import": "import mods.initialinventory.InvHandler;"
}, {
"title": "Artisan Worktables",
"import": "import mods.artisanworktables.Worktable;"
}, {
"title": "JEI Hide",
"import": "mods.jei.JEI.hide;"
}]
```

And then further take those "title" values in the JSON file and essentially replace the data variable with them. I hope this makes sense, something like this:

```
data = {titles in json file}
```

So I can just add to the Json file as I go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
import json

with open('file.json', 'r+') as f:
    content = json.load(f)

data = [[i['title'] for i in content]
```

that `data`variable will be `['Advanced Mortars', 'Initial Inventory', 'Artisan Worktables', 'JEI Hide']`

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed.